# Efficient way to long poll in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I am a beginner in javascript and jquery and was looking for an efficient way to long poll in jquery. 
I came across this piece of code and was puzzled by the attribute **complete:** . I am aware of the use of 'complete' but will this piece of code result in recursive function call?

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({ url: "server", success: function(data){
        //Update your dashboard gauge
        salesGauge.setValue(data.value);

    }, dataType: "json", complete: poll, timeout: 30000 });
})();
```

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: Yes it will be recursive. though, i would argue long polling is never efficient, compared to the alternatives.

Comment: @KevinB what do you suggest then ?

Comment: if it isn't too difficult to implement in your situation, websockets.

Comment: Remember that long polling is controlled by the server, not the client. Also it's an entirely legitimate method (websockets don't work everywhere *cougholdinternetexplorer*). This code just keeps polling. When it gets a response (positive or negative) it makes the connection again.

Comment: To clarify that, if you use this code on a server which doesn't long poll, you will get a *lot* of bandwidth used.

Comment: what i was mainly getting at is whether or not it is efficient is not relevant to your question. You could have answered the question yourself by simply trying it and seeing that it does infact recursively poll. Whether or not it is efficient should probably be a separate question.

Comment: @Dave I have an asynchronus servlet which does the job of Long polling. But I am struggling in the client side how to poll request once server responds.

Comment: @AshwinSurana your current code does just that. is there a problem with it?

Comment: @AshwinSurana I don't see your problem.

Comment: @KevinB Its a recursive call, not efficient for polling requests as it would keep occupying memory in tthe stack for everytime it polls. :/

Comment: @AshwinSurana Right, that's how long polling works. thats the `long` part. the request is kept open for x seconds (30 in this case). it then either returns data or timesout.

Comment: @KevinB Iterative polling wont result in such a problem. That is what I did in my java client program and it worked wonderfully. Trying to achieve the same in javascript.

Comment: Do you have your server ending the request after 30 seconds? javascript can't tell your server to timeout, all it can do is stop listening for a response.

Comment: @Dave My problem here is that recursion would exhaust the memory.

Comment: @kevinB Yes my server handles every request for only a specific amount of time. The problem is only with JS. I am confused on how to poll request.

Comment: @AshwinSurana javascript doesn't recurse like that. You might have an issue with nested scopes, but it won't exhaust the memory. If you are worried about nested scopes, replace the callback with `function(){setTimeout(poll,0)}`. But only do that if you need to. I'm not even sure it would be a problem to not do that.

Comment: @dave thanks a lot :). I hope that should do it. could you post your comment as an answer?

Comment: +1 to cancel downvotes. Question is reasonably clear and people are making bad assumptions about what is being asked, not the OP's fault.

Comment: @AshwinSurana I've included that in my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the recursion by using a short timeout to ensure that the current call stack clears:

```
(function poll(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "server",
        success: function(data){
            //Update your dashboard gauge
            salesGauge.setValue(data.value);
        },
        dataType: "json",
        complete: function () {
            setTimeout(poll, 0);
        },
        timeout: 30000
    });
})();
```

This will execute `poll` as (probably) the next event after the current execution clears. In other words, jQuery will execute the `complete` callback and return from everything until it's finally out of its `onreadystatechange` callback, at which point the JavaScript runtime will execute `poll` again (unless a different event came in and got onto the event queue first, of course).

Comment: There's really no relevant difference between the two, is there? It's not like the $.ajax() call will ever be calling poll() itself. It's only when the server has actually responded (or timed out) that the "complete" handler gets called, so whether you call poll() inside the success function, specify complete: poll, or use the setTimeout() technique, it's all (basically) the same sequence.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP question:

"complete: poll" will call the function again over and over. This would result in quite a bit of bandwidth, possible server timeouts, and if used by enough people could slow your server down.

Comment: not if the server is set up for long-polling, which is what his question is about.